# How to add multiple Media from Disk in Laravel Spatie Media Library?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-medialibrary

I'm saving images from local disk to cloud (DO storage) disk by following codes in controller

```
$claim->addMediaFromDisk($front_image, 'public')->usingFileName("front-image")->toMediaCollection('claim-images', 'do_spaces');
$claim->addMediaFromDisk($right_image, 'public')->usingFileName("right-image")->toMediaCollection('claim-images', 'do_spaces');
$claim->addMediaFromDisk($left_image, 'public')->usingFileName("left-image")->toMediaCollection('claim-images', 'do_spaces');
```

this trick works but saving those images in 3 different directory in cloud storage. But I want all three images in same directory.

I see there is [built in method](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v7/api/adding-files#addmultiplemediafromrequest) for adding multiple media from request. But how can I do it form disk. I was expecting something like `addMultipleMediaFromDisk`(!). Is there any solution ?

*Laravel version: 7.30*

*Spatie media library version: 7.20*

Answer (score 0):

//where the original file is saved on the local disk and the conversions on S3.

```
$media = $claim->addMedia($pathToImage)->storingConversionsOnDisk('s3')
->toMediaCollection('claim-images', 'local');
```